Tabs not aligned in Bootstrap Modal
I´m building a Bootstrap Modal and I want to put some tabs inside this Modal to be able to navigate inside him.
What is happenings is that the tabs displayed are not aligned the proper way like in the following image:
enter image description here
I am building this modal in the Javascript with this code:
BootstrapDialog.show({
          title: "Vouchers Details",
          closable: false,
          message: `
             <!-- Criação das tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" role="tab" aria-controls="menu1" aria-selected="false">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" role="tab" aria-controls="menu2" aria-selected="false">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Conteúdo das tabs -->
    <div class="tab-content mt-3">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu1-tab">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu2-tab">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
          `,
          buttons: [
            {
              label: "Dismiss",
              action: function (dialog) {
                dialog.close();
              },
            },
          ],
        });

I need some help to align this tabs.
I try to use some bootstrap classes and some css and html customization, but it did not solve this problem.

The code you provided seems to be working fine I ran it here, and it's working good, some other code may have effected it please debug your issue and post the actual root of the issue.

@Mohammadsiabbou the problem was related to Boostrap library. The BoostraopDialog.show for some reason interprets a new line as a  tag. For example, if I add a new line between the tabs, the Bootstrap would add a  tag. The solution that I found to solve this problem was to add the "nl2br" property to the BoostrapDialog.



<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary ">
  <div class="container-fluid bg-primary p-2 ">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">Voucher Details</a>
   <div class="justify-content-end mr-2"> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Menu2</a>
        </li></div></div></nav>




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
